# ZF2 routing - How to configure these routes

Tags: php, routes, zend-framework2

I have the following ZF2 configuration:

```
<?php

return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                            '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller' => 'Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'application' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '[:controller[/:action]][/:id][/:pId][/:devId]', //edited by Dibyendu
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'service_manager' => array(
        'abstract_factories' => array(
            'Zend\Cache\Service\StorageCacheAbstractServiceFactory',
            'Zend\Log\LoggerAbstractServiceFactory',
        ),
        'factories' => array(
            'translator' => 'Zend\Mvc\Service\TranslatorServiceFactory',
        ),
    ),
    'translator' => array(
        'locale' => 'en_US',
        'translation_file_patterns' => array(
            array(
                'type'     => 'gettext',
                'base_dir' => __DIR__ . '/../language',
                'pattern'  => '%s.mo',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController',
                'Application\Controller\Upload' => 'Application\Controller\UploadController'
        ),
    ),
    'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'           => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
    // Placeholder for console routes
    'console' => array(
        'router' => array(
            'routes' => array(

            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Now I have controller `Upload` which has three actions:

1. `indexAction`
2. `uploadtestAction`
3. `uploadmusicAction`

In general the url of these pages will be like:

1. http://localhost/zend_test/public/Upload
2. http://localhost/zend_test/public/Upload/uploadtest
3. http://localhost/zend_test/public/Upload/uploadmusic

Respectively, hence I want to make them like:

1. http://localhost/zend_test/public/Upload/upload-home
2. http://localhost/zend_test/public/Upload/upload-test
3. http://localhost/zend_test/public/Upload/musics-upload

The last two will have four parameter in the URL.
How can I implement this?

Comment: Your question is very unclear. What did you try? Why does it not work? You simply copy pasted your complete config. Please remove all irrelevant code from your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have my workspace open, so this is a shot in the dark. *sorry*

Have you tried using an architecture like you'd use for a RESTful service? 
[This file](https://github.com/ardkevin84/zf2-ims/blob/master/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/CategoryClientController.php) is a service controller I use quite frequently, and it gives me routes similar to yours.

- Your controller will 1 action, in the pure sense.
- Your route maps a segment to a param.
- The `indexAction` consumes that param, and passes the method chain on to an internal function of your choosing.

**please** don't judge my service by REST standards. it makes me feel dirty having that service out there :) *have* to update it one day.

In your use-case:

Your route would look something like

```
'upload' => array(
    'type' => 'Literal',
    'options' => array(
      // Change this to something specific to your module
      'route' => '/Upload',
      'defaults' => array(
        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
        'controller' => 'Upload',
      ),
    ),
    'may_terminate' => true,
    'child_routes' => array(
      'client' => array(
        'type' => 'Segment',
        'options' => array(
          'route' => '[/:type][/:id]',
          'constraints' => array(
            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
          ),
          'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Upload',
            'action' => 'index'
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

and your `indexController` will consume `$type` in its switch, to direct the flow.